# LaTeX equations clipped in blogdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, blogdown

[On my blogdown site](https://datalit.netlify.com/2019/03/11/a-compendium-of-control-chart-formulas---variable-charts/) my LaTeX equations get clipped on low resolution devices (eg mobile). Example below. This also happens to tables I put on the same site.

[image]

This was also happening to my plots until I added the `out.width = "100%"` option to my knitr `opts_chunk$set`. How do I prevent this clipping behavior for my R Markdown LaTeX equations written in the following form?

```
$$\textit{Upper Control Limit} = Average + (2.66 \times \textit{Moving Range)}$$
```

Comment: Is it actually clipping your LaTeX equations or can you still side-scroll?

Comment: @Maurits Evers No side scrolling is available. It is a true clip. I'll put a live link to the site in the post now.

Comment: Hmm. The HTML links at the top, the table and the LaTeX formula all get hard-clipped. While this doesn't really help you, at least it seems that this is not uniquely connected to LaTeX (or MathJax).

Comment: I have the same problem on [my site](https://www.bryanshalloway.com/2020/02/06/maximizing-magnetic-volume-the-perfect-bowl/) where large formulas get cut-off if viewed from a smartphone or smaller screen.  Not sure if customizing the MathJax set-up would be an option, but was struggling in doing that... any progress?